# How can I transform linked records into a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building an application with a database table for games. All games have different attributes, although some attributes are the same for each game, mostly name and type. I store all the attributes in a separate table so that they can be searchable. Every game has a `has_many` relationship to attributes.

```
Table games
id       int     primary key
name     string  unique
type     string

Table attributes
id       int     primary_key
game_id  int
name     string
value    text
```

For example the game "Nyan Cat Adventures in Space" (made up name) could have the following attributes:

```
id   game_id    name      value
4    344        dlc       99
5    344        packages  2209
6    344        language  "Space Cat"
7    344        dlc       551
```

I need the attributes to be fully searchable (and indexed). I would like to be able to transform the attributes into a hash so that I could access certain attributes like this: `game.attributes['dlc']`. Note however that some attributes can have the same name. What is the best way to achieve this, should I extend ActiveRecord::Base? Is there a function or callback I can use?

Comment: Your given example of games.attributes['dlc'] is one that has two values.  What are you expecting for those?

Comment: That `game.attributes['dlc']` is an array (or hash) with all values.

Comment: map through the records to turn each one into a hash, you can have the hash include associated records this way too.

Comment: This was my thought too. I was thinking of using the `after_find` callback, can you think of anything that would render this inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of records like `games = Game.all`
and `Game` objects have associated `DLC` objects, you can do this:

```
game_hashes_with_dlc_info = games.map do |game|
  game.attributes.merge(dlc: game.dlc.map(&:attributes))
end
```

---

in response to your comment

Given a hash like `{ foo: "1", foo: "2", bar: "1", bar: "2" }`

that you want to turn into `{ foo: ["1", "2"], bar: ["1", "2"] }`

```
hash_1.reduce({}) do |new_hash, (hash_1_key, hash_1_val)|
  if new_hash.has_key? hash_1_key
    new_hash[hash_1_key].push(hash_1_val)
  else
    new_hash[hash_1_key] = [hash_1_val]
  end
  new_hash
end
```

this has the effect of making *all* the hash values arrays, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, `Game` objects have `Attribute` objects, some of which - sometimes more than one per `Game` - have a property `name` equal to `dlc`. My thought after some more research was to use the `after_find` callback to `map` through all attributes of a game and put them in a hash.

Comment: oh, i see what you mean now. your focus is on making a special case for hash key collision, so that when reading the values get turned into an array. What is the benefit of structuring hashes like this in the first place if you're going to have to jump hoops to get the data out? Regardless, I'll update my answer showing you.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use group_by to get what you want.  Something along the lines of the following will probably work.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :game_attributes, :class_name => "Attribute"

    def game_attributes
        result = super
        result.to_a.group_by{|a| a["name"]}
    end
end
```

This means that game.game_attributes["dlc"] will return all Attribute objects associated with that game.  This does end up hiding the active record relation so you may want to define a new method rather than override this one depending on what you intend to do.